# How to make options in popover which is inside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs in which i ve placed selectable  for pop up. I am basically trying to add certain options in pop up section but the pop up seems to be too small. 
Here is my code

```css
.box {
      top: 33px;
    left: 346px;
    position: relative;
    width: 160px;
    right: auto;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: auto;
}
.four{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: rgba(217, 83, 79, 0.8);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.six{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #009933;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.five{
      box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid  #009933;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.popover{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left: 80% !important;
    
}

.popover .arrow{
    display:none;
   
    
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1">
  <div class="four">
  adam
    <i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"  title="Help" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" width="100%"  data-content="1453453"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="five">
    
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">
   <div class="six">
     <i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"  title="Help" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" width="100%"  data-content="1453453"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="five">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

on here https://jsfiddle.net/zohaibrehman/4z6uydge/23/ shows complete result but i dont know why javascript is not working here.

The output of above fiddle is this when i click ***i*** in circle:

[image]

What i am trying to achieve something like this, at right corner:

[image]

Such that when this is clicked it should show this:

[image]

Sorry for my bad English. There is something which i am not focusing. So please help. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Tou should add styles to your popover, width and height, and reculc the left

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lc35bm2/). I have only changed popover style

```
.popover{
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px !important;
  right: 0;
  left: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, One more thing can i move this "i" to top right corner? of div?

Comment: Yes by using the position property like this 
.i-icon{    position: absolute;
    right: -4px;
    top: -4px;
    color: #110404;
}

Comment: Ok, i am also trying to add +, setting sybmol and dust-bin type contents on pop up. Can u guide? I ve also mentioned in last two pictures as what my objective is. That pics have rounded pop up but on jsfiddle its currently in other form